# How to avoid the fat/polluted interface in this scenario of C++ design - OOPS?

Tags: c++, oop, uml

We are writing a generic middleware for the gadget- DTV. We have a module called ContentMgr, which is a base class. Now, for the different customer needs, we have the VideoconContentMgr ( for instance)- which is derived from ContentMgr.

```
class ContentMgr
{
  public:

virtual void setContent()
{
  cout<<"Unused function";
}

};

class VideoconContentMgr: public ContentMgr
{
  virtual void setContent()
  {
     cout<<"Do some useful computation;
  }

};
```

client code - based on the product type - the

/** if the product is generic **/
ContentMgr *product = new ContentMgr();

/** If the product is videocon **/
ContentMgr *product = new VideoconContentMgr();

My question is according to the Interface Segregation Principle - One should avoid fat/polluted interfaces. How can I avoid the polluted method - setContent() here. For the generic product,setContent() is not useful. However, for the videocon product it is useful. How can I avoid the fat/polluted  method setContent()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the generic product, `setContent()` is not useful. However, for the videocon product it is useful.

One solution is to keep the member function where it is useful - put it into `VideoconContentMgr` only, and use it in the context specific to the `VideoconContentMgr` subtype:

```
/** if the product is generic **/ ContentMgr *product = new ContentMgr();

/** If the product is videocon **/ {
    VideoconContentMgr *vcm = new VideoconContentMgr();
    vcm->setContent();
    ContentMgr *product = vcm;
}
```

If the usefulness of the member function specific to a subclass extends past the initialization time, use a [visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)-like approach. Subclass-specific code remains bound to subclasses, but now you add a visitor that does nothing for a generic class, and calls `setContent()` on `VideoconContentMgr` class:

```
struct ContentMgrVisitor {
  virtual void visitGeneric(ContentMgr& m) {};
  virtual void visitVideo(VideoconContentMgr& vm) {};
};

struct ContentMgr
{
  virtual void accept(ContentMgrVisitor& v)
  {
    v.visitGeneric(this);
  }
};

struct VideoconContentMgr: public ContentMgr
{
  virtual void setContent()
  {
     cout<<"Do some useful computation;
  }
  virtual void accept(ContentMgrVisitor& v)
  {
     v.visitVideo(this);
  }
};
```

Now a client who wants to call `setContent` can do it from a visitor:

```
class SetContentVisitor : public ContentMgrVisitor {
    void visitVideo(VideoconContentMgr& vm) {
        vm.setContent();
    }
};
...
ContentMgr *mgr = ... // Comes from somewhere
SetContentVisitor scv;
mgr->accept(scv);
```

Comment: How a client can set the content at any time - setContent()? You have put up only in the constructor. Also, I want polymorphism.

Comment: @dexterous_stranger Polymorphism does not make sense when a call applies to only a single class in a hierarchy, and makes no sense for other classes. I'll edit to show a quick example of the visitor-like implementation.